# Angular Controller Automatically Calls Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller I've created in Angular and there is a function in it that needs to be called from my view. My problem is that upon loading, the page, the function automatically gets called. I only want it to get called when I call it.

```
angular.module("mainProject")
.controller("randomCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

    $scope.callApi = function () {
        console.log("Don't Execute Yet!");
    };
});
```

Is there a way to make it so I can call the callApi function from a ng-click, but for it not to fire upon loading?

Comment: Can you make a plunker of this issue? This should not be happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not be called when your page is loaded. Something else must be going on.

Comment: You're right, just figured out my issue, I had the function in a watchCollection, that was automatically firing on page load and this called the function. Thanks